# Images showing on Heroku with image_tag, but not showing in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image that I'm rendering the path with image_tag:

```
<%= image_tag "piechart.png" %>
```

...which renders as:

```
<img src="/images/piechart.png" />
```

The file resides in app/assets/images/

I can't try to load the image in the browser as it tells me:

```
No route matches [GET] "/images/piechart.png"
```

Do I need to edit the routes.rb file for assets? As mentioned, it shows in Heroku (but as `/assets/piechart-4f7638b49b22f54811bb6cffc3171810.png`)

Thanks

Comment: is it only happening with this image ?

Comment: Actually, this is the only image I'm using in the app currently

Comment: Looks like assets pipeline is disabled in your development environment.

Comment: All I see in environments/development.rb is config.assets.debug = true. I've tried setting to false as well as adding config.assets.enabled = true but no change. Btw I'm resetting rails server each time. Am I changing the correct file/setting?